# LINQ to XML Multiple Selects

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

**Edit**: Here is an example XML document I am trying to parse: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/1011699/ (view source).

Here are the items I'm trying to retrieve:

- Title (tbody/tr/td/a)
- Author (tbody/tr/td)
- Url (also stored in the author node)
- Date (tbody/tr/td/div/div)
- Replies (tbody/tr/td)
- Views (also stored in the above node)

I do a 'pre-query' so I don't have to traverse as far down for each following query:

```
var threads =
    from allThreads in xmlThreadList.Descendants(ns + "tbody")
                                    .Descendants(ns + "tr")
                                    .Descendants(ns + "td")
    select allThreads;
```

I have an XML document that represents a list of forum threads. In each thread there are different children that hold different pieces of information that I would like to retrieve. Currently I do this by querying the XML document multiple times. Is there a way to extract this information in a single query and store it in IEnumerable? The way I'm doing it now seems inefficient.

```
    // array of xelements that contain the title and url
    var threadTitles =
        (from allThreads in threads.Descendants(ns + "a")
        where allThreads.Parent.Attribute("class").Value.Equals("post-title")
        select allThreads).ToArray();

    // array of strings of author names
    var threadAuthors =
        (from allThreads in threads
        where allThreads.Attribute("class").Value.Equals("post-author")
        select allThreads.Value.Trim()).ToArray();

    // ...
    // there are several more queries like this
    // ...

    // for loop to populate a list with all the extracted data
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < threadTitles.Length; i++, j++)
    {
        ThreadItem threadItem = new ThreadItem();

        threadItem.Title = threadTitles[i].Value.Trim();
        threadItem.Author = threadAuthors[i];
        threadItem.Url = Path.Combine(_url, threadTitles[i].Attribute("href").Value);
        threadItem.Date = threadDates[i];
        threadItem.Replies = threadRepliesAndViews[j++];
        threadItem.Views = threadRepliesAndViews[j];
        _threads.Add(threadItem);
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm new the whole LINQ to XML scene.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the XML you are accessing to? Please specify also what are exactly the informations you'd like to extract. :)

Comment: I've posted a bit more information now, let me know if you need any more--thanks!

Comment: can you show us whats in the threads variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
string ns = "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}";

var doc = XDocument.Load("http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/1011699/");
var threads = from tr in doc.Descendants(ns + "tbody").Elements(ns + "tr")
              let elements = tr.Elements(ns + "td")
              let title = elements.First(a => a.Attribute("class").Value == "post-title").Element(ns + "a")
              let author = elements.First(a => a.Attribute("class").Value == "post-author")
              let replies = elements.First(a => a.Attribute("class").Value == "post-replies")
              let views = elements.First(a => a.Attribute("class").Value == "post-views")
              select new
              {
                  Title = title.Value.Trim(),
                  Url = title.Attribute("href").Value.Trim(),
                  Author = author.Value.Trim(),
                  Replies = int.Parse(replies.Value),
                  Views = int.Parse(views.Value)
              };

foreach (var item in threads)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
from thread in threads
select new ThreadItem() {
   Title = thread.Descendants(ns + "a").First( title => title.Parent.Attribute("class").Value.Equals("post-title")),
  Date = date query part

  ect.... 
}
```

this will gain some speed as you dont parse the whole xml block again and again, instead you just look through each smaller thread several times extracting different info each time.

i'd be interested to know which turns out faster as you are effectively trading the hope that the whole element item fits in the cache and thus gives you quick access to it when you execute all the small queries on it, with the hope (in your old code) that the branch predictor on your cpu will tune to each long query be executed giving better speed .

Comment: I used AS-CII's answer above, and after a few runs comparing the times they average about the same but it's just so much cleaner to do it in a single call rather than the way I was doing it